# single spacing in table cell in TeX

Tags: tables, spacing

I am looking for a solution 
1. single space 
2. justfy line
Can anyone please help me?
here is the code.

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{table}[h!]
    %\centering
    \begin{adjustbox}{max width=\textwidth}
        \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|}
            \hline
            \multirow{3}{*}{1} & \multicolumn{4}{l|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}} \bf Implementation of a Smart and Sustainable Watering System using Arduino \\\bf for  Plants Sprinkler – \textit{FYP, Degree}\hfill\vadjust{} \end{tabular}}                                                                                                                                             \\ \cline{2-5} 
            & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Synopsis}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Duration} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Manpower} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Status} \\ \cline{2-5} 
            & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}} An Arduino based automatic sprinkler system for \\the automatic plants' watering where the power \\supply is maintained by the solar system.  \end{tabular}                                                                                                & 2 sem   & 1 student & Completed \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
    \end{adjustbox}
\end{table}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

Comment: Could you rewrite your code [including the preamble containing packages] or send a picture of the table pertaining to your question? I have a hard time figuring out the code especially it is not spaced out well. Thanks

Comment: Please tell us how you've modified the line spacing for your document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this? (Observe that I would caution *against* using an `adjustbox` environment.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|l|>{\RaggedRight}X|c|c|c|}
\hline
1 & \multicolumn{4}{p{0.9\textwidth}|}{\bfseries Implementation of a Smart and Sustainable Watering System using Arduino for Plants Sprinkler –-- \textit{FYP, Degree}} \\ 
\cline{2-5} 
& Synopsis & Duration & Manpower & Status \\ 
\cline{2-5} 
& An Arduino based automatic sprinkler system for the automatic plants' watering where the power supply is maintained by the solar system. 
& 2 sem & 1 student & Completed \\ 
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, Thanks a lot, everyone. Its great now! :)